# Excel VBA Beginner - Getting Run time error '9' Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a simple macro to change a date format mm/dd/yy to just the month full name. This is what I have using a days worth experience in VBA. I'm missing the error here

```
Sub ChangeDate()

    Dim Last As Integer
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim Counter As Integer

    For Counter = 2 To Last
        Dim Month As String
        Month = Left(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2), 1)

        If Month = "7" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = "July"

        ElseIf Month = "8" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = "August"

        ElseIf Month = "9" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = "September"
        End If

    Next Counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Declare Counter As Long.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value2,"mmmm")`

Comment: ... or just change `Worksheets("Sheet1").range("B2:B" & last).numberformat = "mmmm"`

Comment: Why you need to use code? You can do it changing `Format Cells` to Custom using `mmm`

Comment: @DavidG. - I think that should be `mmmm`.

Comment: @DavidG. I am really just trying to learn VBA for future projects so I'm starting with something simple. Or so I thought haha

Comment: For future reference, a multiple If ... ElseIf ... end if like this is a good place for a Select Case statement.

Comment: @zroberts51 Ok, I got you, but is better for you if you don't try to replicate functions that can be done in a easy way. When you need to do something bigger, sometimes you forget to use those easy tricks and try to write a full code for simple stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
Sub ChangeDate()
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim Last As Integer

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Counter = 2 To Last
        Dim Month As String
        Month = Left(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 1), 1)

        If Month = "7" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = "July"

        ElseIf Month = "8" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = "August"

        ElseIf Month = "9" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 2).Value = "September"
        End If
    Next Counter
End Sub
```

This code reads the date in column 1 and puts the month in column 2.
Is a good advice to use `Case` statement instead of `ElseIf`.